# inference variable T has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, generics

Given a method with the following signature.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int dummyMethod(List<T> list, T elem) {
  // Body
}
```

Of the following two methods only the first compiles successfully.

```
public void call() {
  MyClass v = new MyClass();
  List<MyClass> ls = new ArrayList<>();
  dummyMethod(ls, v);
}

public void brokenCall() {
  Comparable<MyClass> v = new MyClass();
  List<Comparable<MyClass>> ls = new ArrayList<>();
  dummyMethod(ls, v);    // Compilation error here.
}
```

The error returned by javac (JDK 8u60) reads as follows:

```
.\MyClass.java:23: error: method dummyMethod in class MyClass cannot be applied to given types;
    dummyMethod(ls, v);    // Compilation error here.
    ^
  required: List<T>,T
  found: List<Comparable<MyClass>>,Comparable<MyClass>
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: MyClass,Comparable<MyClass>
    lower bounds: Comparable<MyClass>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Comparable<T> declared in method <T>dummyMethod(List<T>,T)
1 error
```

I'm confused as to why the types of the variables provided as arguments to dummyMethod in brokenCall don't match it's signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `brokenCall`, you're making `T` = `Comparable<MyClass>`, but `Comparable<MyClass> extends Comparable<Comparable<MyClass>>` is invalid.